# Prevent user refresh or quit while axios request processing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios

I'm developing a Web Application where I use Axios.get requests. Since Axios is asynchronous, i'm doing an async function and an await axios.all :

```
 async handleSubmit(){
            const ops=[]
            for(i=0;i<this.state.rowsNumber;i++){ 
                let op = axios.get(myrequest,{headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}} )
                        ops.push(op);
                }
            let res = await axios.all(ops);
}
```

It works perfectly but myrequest takes some time to be executed and I would like to alert the user if he refreshes or leaves the page when the axios request is processing.

How may I proceed?

Thanks for your future answers

Comment: As stated in the answers there is no reliable way to prevent a user from leaving the page. You should instead try to design your application in a way that does not rely on the client completing a request. It is generally more annoying than useful for the user to prevent navigating away from a page and I would consider it a bad ui practice to do so. In fact there could be many other reasons a pending request fails that are even less under your control.

Comment: Actually as soon as the URL is called with axios, it is executed, but for the user experience, I would like to alert them if they reload during the process because when the process is ended, the display of datas will be updated.

If they refresh because they don't know what is happening and click again on the button, it might send another request and spam my backend.

I implemented a Loading Bar but i'm afraid of user who don't even care of this bar and refresh without waiting it to be complete

Comment: Well in my opinion these are several unrelated problems that can be solved differently. One thing is spamming your backend if done by your app is a programming error and if done by the user is a throttling or permission issue. You should instead disable the button on a new render and disallow performing that command on your server if there is a data update process running or whatever is happening. This way the you prevent the user from accidently "spaming" your backend in the first place. Computation heavy tasks on the backend ideally should also be made async not blocking a response.

Comment: But admittedly these steps require quite a bit of work so it might be to advanced depending on the time budget. Just wanted to point out better solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, I will consider them because I agree with you, my design is may be not well designed for this case !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use window.onbeforeunload function to have a confirmation popup when user clicked refresh/close/leave browser.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) { ... });
```

Then just remove listener once Axios is done.

Comment: Hi

I know this solution but is it possible to call this function only if the axios request is processing 

I would like to set a boolean to true at the beginning of the request and if the request is ended set it to false. So if he refreshes AND boolean===true : alert the user. Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: You could use an async dispatch. You have to set a state to let the app know that it is undergoing an axios call and turn on the listener for onbeforeunload. And then just remove it once axios call is done. You could add and remove event listener by window.addEventListener and window.removeEventListener, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of  `window.onbeforeunload`, while you can't prevent totally an user to refresh you can notify that a request is pending:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return "A XHR request is pending, are you sure you want to leave ?";
    }
```

Beware:

> More recent web browsers won't show the custom message, because it was
>   considered to be a security issue.

Comment: Hi

I know this solution but is it possible to call this function only if the axios request is processing 

I would like to set a boolean to true at the beginning of the request and if the request is ended set it to false. So if he refreshes AND boolean===true : alert the user. Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of setting and unsetting a bool flag,  add and remove the listener to get the desired result

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

How do you proceed to add or remove a listener?

Comment: With window.removeListener, but you have to name your function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Answer (score 0):

By this way you will get `refresh` event.

```
if (window.performance) {
 if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
   alert( "Reload page" );
 } else {
   alert( "Not reloaded");
 }
}
```